# PNG Not copying Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

This is an extension to a question I could not get answered/solved. So I decided to try and work around the situation with a copy and paste command. However when I try and copy the image selected it does not allow me to paste it, the menu does not pop up to allow a paste, only copy comes up which I assume means it not copying to the pasteboard. Here is where I am:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *file = stickers2[indexPath.item];

    NSLog (@"%d",indexPath.item);
    NSLog (@"%@ FILE STRING",file);
    NSString *sticker = [file stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@""];
    NSLog (@"%@ STICKER STRING",sticker);

        imageItem = [UIImage imageNamed:sticker];
    NSError* error = nil;
    UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sticker ofType:@"png"];

    NSLog(@"%@ IS THE IMAGE PATH!", imagePath);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath options:0 error: &error];
    [pb setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.jpeg"];

    if (data == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to read file, error %@", error);
    }


    NSLog(@"%@", pb);
    NSLog(@"%@",data);


    if (delegate != nil) [delegate didSelectSticker:sticker];{
        NSLog(@"HAHHAHHA");
    };
    NSLog (@"%@",file);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

NSLog:

```
2016-05-25 13:42:58.320 [4469:1236352] 28
2016-05-25 13:42:58.320 [4469:1236352] stickersend28@2x.png FILE STRING
2016-05-25 13:42:58.321 [4469:1236352] stickersend28@2x STICKER STRING
2016-05-25 13:42:58.336 [4469:1236352] /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F60DE305-F6F2-4562-BD66-CCB7FA9992AE/SomeApp.app/stickersend28@2x.png IS THE IMAGE PATH!
2016-05-25 13:42:58.384 [4469:1236352] <UIPasteboard: 0x12e8c3520>

//This Continues for a lot longer than posted.
2016-05-25 13:42:58.388 4469:1236352] <89504e47 0d0a1a0a 00000004 43674249 50002006 2cb87766 0000000d 49484452 000000d2 000000d2 08060000 003f999e 42000009 f7694343 50494343 2050726f 66696c65 0000ad96 09d81c1e aaa8ca38 239207eff70c 3f000000 0049454e 44ae4260 82>
2016-05-25 13:42:58.403[4469:1236352] HAHHAHHA
2016-05-25 13:42:58.403[4469:1236352] stickersend28@2x.png
```

ChatView.m

```
- (void)paste:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage *sticker = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;
    NSLog(@"CALLED IT");
    NSLog(@"%@",sticker);
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sticker, 1);
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [item setValue:imageData forKey:(NSString*)kUTTypeJPEG];
    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] addItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:item]];

        NSLog(@"%@ IMAGEDATA",imageData);
        NSLog(@"%@ITEM",item);

}




  //NSLog

       2016-05-26 13:00:30.906 [5297:1473004] CALLED IT
    2016-05-26 13:00:30.907 [5297:1473004] <UIImage: 0x1270c3600>, {105, 105}
    2016-05-26 13:00:30.907 [5297:1473004] <UIPasteboard: 0x127204130>

ImageData and Item return Walls of Numbers.
```

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfFile` requires a complete path, not just a filename.

Comment: @rmaddy how to get the path of the sticker the user selected?

Comment: @BARIIIIIIICODE, from your _model_... maybe.

Comment: @BARIIIIIIICODE Where is the image stored? Is it in your app bundle? The Documents folder? Elsewhere?

Comment: @rmaddy It's stored within the app.

Comment: I found the image path but NSLog reads an odd string of lots of numbers, updating up top.

Comment: Paste command is still not available.

Comment: Now that you seem to be properly putting the data in the pasteboard, you should provide details about where and how you try to make use of pasting the image.

Comment: Pasting into a messaging text on separate view via the user holding their finger down to open the copy/paste menu

Comment: It does paste into other apps (Native iOS Messenger. Facebook, ETC.) Just not in my app.

Comment: @rmaddy Have to paste function available by    UIImage *sticker = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image; in viewDidLoad, paste is empty however. Copied an image from Google, and when pasted it pastes URL of image and not image.